# How to set the image at the center of button and make the buttons at the center of constraints layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set the icon or image at the center of the rounded button as I need also to me the buttons at the center of the `Constraint layout`

as this is my related `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.164"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cafeBtn"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/espresso"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/drinksBtn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/restBtn"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_grey"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/eaatt"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/drinksBtn"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drinksBtn"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_white"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/drinkss"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/restBtn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cafeBtn"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the buttons background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#00c8f8"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#00c8f8"
        />
</shape>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#c8c7cc"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#00c8f8"
        />
</shape>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#00c8f8"
        />
</shape>
```

[image]

I hope someone could help me to solve this

Comment: Can you share your code for the buttons background?you probably not centering the image there.

Comment: @YakirMalka  check edits please :D

Comment: sorry padding is the right way BUT, try using "gravity=center" on each button

Comment: @YakirMalka I already added you will find in the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `android:drawable...` attributes of `Button`, it would be better to replace these Buttons with ImageViews, adding the background of the buttons to these ImageViews. You will still be able to add an `OnClickListener` to your ImageViews, making them act as Buttons.

So your View (without the constraints) should look something like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cafeBtn"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:src="@drawable/espresso" />
```

If you want to decrease the image size, you can adjust its padding as:

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

---

#### Edit:

If you also want to center all three buttons on screen, the whole idea is to add the correct constraints. Replace your whole layout with the following:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cafeBtn"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:src="@drawable/espresso"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/drinksBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drinksBtn"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_white"
        android:src="@drawable/drinkss"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/restBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cafeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/restBtn"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_grey"
        android:src="@drawable/eaatt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/drinksBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but how about for making the three button align at the center of constraints?

Comment: You want the 3 buttons centered on screen?

Comment: Feky yes exactly